# Need to have two volume levels for a magnetic transducer buzzer

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, 555

I am using an ATMEGA328PB TQFP and the  Arduino IDE to activate a magnetic transducer buzzer (CUI CSS-14B20-SMT-TR).  I'm using the Arduino Tone Library to produce 3 short beeps and then a 1 second pause, then repeats.  I need the volume of these beeps to increase to, and remain at, a second volume level after approximately  10 seconds.

I only have one pin available, so cannot activate a second circuit with a second pin.  Using ATMEGA328PB pin 25 (Arduino pin 16/A2).

1. Is there a circuit I could add to connect to a lower resistance path after a designated time or number of Tone commands, thereby increasing volume?  Looking around, could it be a resistor, capacitor, transistor circuit?  Or a 555 timer?  Not sure if these would work considering the beep signal is not a steady "on" signal that could charge a cap, or trigger a 555 (or could it), but square waves that turn on and off.
2. Is there a way to control volume in software using Duty Cycle and the Tone command?

Here is the schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Here is the Arduino Code, which works for 1 volume.

```
int Speaker = 16;
unsigned long beep_previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis=0;
int BuzzerState = LOW; 
int Short_beep_count = 0;

void setup() {

pinMode(Speaker, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {

  beep();   // call beep function
  }


void beep()
{
  const long LongInterval = 800;
  const long ShortInterval = 75;  
  int Time;

//Short Delay
currentMillis = millis();
  if ((currentMillis - beep_previousMillis >= ShortInterval) && Short_beep_count <4)
 {
     if ((BuzzerState == HIGH) && (Short_beep_count < 4))
      {
        BuzzerState = LOW;
        noTone(Speaker);
        currentMillis = millis();
        beep_previousMillis = currentMillis;
        Short_beep_count = Short_beep_count +1; //counting LOWs
      }

    else {          
          BuzzerState = HIGH;
          tone(Speaker,2730);
          currentMillis = millis();
          beep_previousMillis = currentMillis;  
          }
 }

//Long Delay
if ((currentMillis - beep_previousMillis >= LongInterval) &&  Short_beep_count >=4)
 {        
        if(Short_beep_count >= 4)
         { Short_beep_count = 0;
         }
        BuzzerState = HIGH;
        tone(Speaker,2730);
        currentMillis = millis();
        beep_previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}
```

Comment: You may find the frequency response of the transducer is poor, and you may be able to exploit that. Frequency F1 may have one volume and frequency F2 (try 2*F1 or 4*F1 because notes on the octave sound similar) may be much louder.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Interesting idea.  Tried it but higher multiples made ticking sounds, and 1/2 multiple was obviously lower tone.  Would have been a simple solution though.

Comment: If the tone is a series of pulses generated by an Arduino timer, you might try duty cycle = 5% (quiet) and 50% (loudest).

Comment: That would be the easiest solution.  I am using the Arduino Tone Library https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/
I do not see how to affect Duty Cycle.